# Chrome doesn't open in our company Desktop

Tags: google-chrome

In our company, desktop Chrome doesn't open only see on bottom bar where you can see which applications is on, but when I click to chrome that doesn't open.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: There is no picture to see. I've removed the link to your company website as it's unnecessary. If you would like assistance, be sure to edit your question to include which version of Ubuntu you're using, and any supporting information that might help with a solution.

Comment: Try running "google-chrome-stable" in the terminal and give us back the results.

Comment: also, you have not provided any version information